# Make eclipse pdt default editor for php, css etc. files in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: php, css, editor, ubuntu-12.04, eclipse-pdt

I downloaded Eclipse php recently. When i want to open a css or php file it doesn't show option for eclipse, not even in the other applications list.

I want to set Eclipse as my default editor to handle such kind of files.

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-51.xhtml

Comment: Questions which **directly involve tools used primarily for programming** are on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this question more than a month ago and i have found an answer to it, Here is the eclipse.desktop file which needs to be added in the /usr/share/applications directory

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse IDE
Exec=eclipse %f
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;Application;Development;
StartupNotify=true
```

Adding %f after 'eclipse' added eclipse in the list of 'other applications' and then i 'set it as default' for css files.

Comment: I'd seen your question [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/315252/25726) and you have not added any answer there